# How do I fix artifacts caused by sculpting with dyntopo?

Tags: sculpting, artifacts, smooth

When I sculpt using dyntopo, it sometimes causes edges to overlap each other, causing artifacts to appear, which are exaggerated when I turn on shade smooth.
[image]

Is there any way to fix this? If not, how do I avoid this happening when I sculpt? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 3D Printing addon, shipped with blender.

1. In edit mode, use it to select all intersecting face.
2. Increase the selection a couple of times. Press control and plus on the numeric keyboard.
3. Decrease the selection, but slighly less steps than in step 2. Press control and minus on the numeric keyboard.
4. Smooth vertices a couple of times. Don't over do it.

Repeat until all intersections are gone.

This will smooth problem areas. Sometimes, if the mesh has formed a self intersecting loop, you can as step 2.5 do "Shrink/Fatten" (ALT+S) with a positive amount. Then do some smoothing.

The trick can be to get the right selection.

With this intersection.... (The red line indicates the flow)

[image]

After using grow and shrink selection, we get this:

[image]

And now Smooth Vertices is much more effective.